# API to check OneDrive file status

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

Is there an API in Windows 8.1 to check the status of a OneDrive file? I would like to know whether the file has been replicated to the local disk or it is just a dummy representation of a file in the cloud that doesn't take up local disk space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information can be retrieved by calling
StorageFile.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770652.aspx)

method and passing it "System.OfflineAvailability" ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787532(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

in the list of properties to be retrieved.

Function will return a dictionary that will contain one of the 3 possible values:
0 - not available offline
1 - available offline
2 - not applicatble (not a SkyDrive/OneDrive file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StorageFile.IsAvailable property. See the following quickstart article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn467360.aspx

EDIT: in fact, as @Ghostrider mentions in the comment, this answer is incorrect. @Ghostrider has [found the correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23445227/664533)

Comment: Unfortunately is available is true if "file is local, is cached locally, or can be downloaded." so it doesn't discriminate between "online only" and "available offline" files which is what I need to do.

Comment: Yes, you're right. And now I see you've found the solution. Nice work.